# How to make tooltip on hovering mouse over a button

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, mouseevent, toolkit

I am c# silverlight(5) beginner and not a bit know about how to make tool tip. In fact i couldnt find any option in toolbox for tool tip.

What i have to do is to show a tooltip when mouse hover a button. Suppose if i have button like this :

```
<Button Content="{Binding Path=Id}"
        Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowPopupCommand,
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=data:DataGrid}}"/>
```

Now how to create a ToolTip on this button in ViewModel.cs class ?

Could someone please give me guidance on how to create ToolTip in c# silverlight application using MVVM approach. Any piece of code for help is really appreciated. Would be a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Button
    ToolTipService.ToolTip="ToolTip based on the mouse."
    ToolTipService.Placement="Mouse"/>
```

If you need to display any `FrameworkElements` (and not just text) you can set the tooltip like this:

```
<Button>
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <Border Background="Pink">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image .../>
                <TextBlock .../>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

Comment: but it should open a dialog on hovering mouse which will disappear as i remove mouse over it. and How i will handle it in ViewModel.cs ? Because it has to work MVVM approach

Comment: @user234839: It will show a box with the tooltip text. What do you mean by "open a dialog"? And if you are using an MVVM approach opening a tooltip from Viewmodel would be wrong in my eyes. Do you mean you want to bind a string from the viewmodel?

Comment: I have to show a child window . Is it possible ? If not then do you know another way to do in silverlight?. I will open a window on mouse hover (Not necessary we use button we can use text box if you want, but mouse hover to it must show a box/window or dialog which on removing the mouse over it will not display any more). Is it possible to display a child window ?

Comment: @user234839: I'm not convinced that you really need to show a [`ChildWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). This sounds more like "need to display more than just text". Do my edits solve your problem?

Comment: but there is no Mvvm approch on this updated part. I mean no binding or anything.

Comment: and i am not able to do Content="{Binding Path=Id}" this Inside it

Comment: I mean i am not able to display the name of button in code in c# thats whi i am talking about Binding. and their may be the possibility that i need to put a combobox in  <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

Comment: IT WRKED BUT I USED GRID INSTEAD OF stackpanel

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<Button Content="{Binding Path=Id}"
        Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowPopupCommand,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=data:DataGrid}}"
        ToolTip="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks bhai but it must show a big box which will conwtain some button and textbox as well

Comment: The property `ToolTip` is only available in WPF.